# The most exciting project this/that year was

Tags: adjectives, demonstrative

Suppose we have a list of paragraphs, each describing a company's achievements in a particular year, and in one of these we find:

> 2009: The most exciting project **this** year was the construction of a new refinery.

wouldn't **this** jar with the use of the past tense? Shouldn't we use **that**:

> 2009: The most exciting project **that** year was the construction of a new refinery.

Or are both allowable?

P.S.

What if we substitute **is** for **was**:

> 2009: The most exciting project **this** year **is** the construction of a new refinery.

Would that flip the situation, with **this** becoming the norm and **that** an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either "this" or "that" works in this sentence.

It is true that in general, if you say "this year" you mean the current year. That is, I am writing this in 2014, so if today I said "this year" I would mean 2014.

But here the writer has just introduced the year in question: 2009. So at that point references to "this year" would be understood to refer to 2009.

Think about how it works if we are talking about something other than a year. Like if I said, "I bought a house in Ohio. This house had gray siding." By "this house" you would surely understand me to mean the house in Ohio, not necessarily my current house.

If only one thing has been introduced, then both "this" and "that" refer to the same thing. My previous sentences could have said, "I bought a house in Ohio. That house had gray siding" and the meaning would be the same. If you introduce two things, then normally "this" refers to one and "that" to the other. Usually "this" refers to the one that is closer in time or space, or to the one that was most recently mentioned. Like, "I bought a house in Ohio 20 years ago. Just recently I bought a house in Michigan. This house has aluminum siding. That house had vinyl siding." "This" here would be understood to mean the house in Michigan as it is the one I bought more recently and the one last mentioned.

We do not normally use the present tense when talking about a past event. I understand some languages have a "historical present", but this is rarely used in English. I suppose one of the most common uses is in lists of dates and events like this. "2008: Fred Jones takes over as president of the company. 2009: Our most exciting project this year is construction of a new refinery. 2010: The new refinery blows up killing 300 people." Etc. In that case I think you would have to use "this is", you couldn't say "that is" because of the immediacy of the wording.